# Seaborn, how do i add a reference line on a graph from my dataframe? "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have written this working script to iterate through my `dataframe` and make a series of line plots for every gene name in my dataframe. What I would like to do now is have a vertical line on every plot that corresponds to a value in one of my dataframe columns.

In my code below, the vertical line I have is statically set at 10, but I would like it to reflect the value in column `zed`. When I input `x=zed` I get the following error `could not convert string to float`. How can I set this up so that the number in the column `zed` for a specific gene is assigned to `x` since it is only able to accept an integer? I feel like there is a simple solution to this that I am totally missing.

[image]

Here is a really poorly drawn example of what each of the graphs I hope to generate will resemble, where the dotted blue line is the line in question, and the red line is my data.

```
i=1    
for element in df['genenumber']:
    if element == i:
        patientnumdf= df[df["genenumber"]==element]
        i = i+1

        g = sns.FacetGrid(patientnumdf, col="", col_wrap=4, size=4, ylim=(0,100))
        g = g.map(plt.axvline, x=10, ls=":", c='0.5')
        g = g.map(plt.plot, "x", "y",color = "red")
        plt.title= "gene:%s"%element
```

here is an example dataframe for 1 genenumber for the above script:

```
gene    y axis  x axis  pt #    gene-pt#    zed genenumber
ASXL1   40  1712    1   ASXL1-1 1857    1
ASXL1   26  1835    1   ASXL1-1 1857    1
ASXL1   17  249 2   ASXL1-2 272 1
ASXL1   34  1   3   ASXL1-3 110 1
ASXL1   0   98  3   ASXL1-3 110 1
ASXL1   36  10  4   ASXL1-4 105 1
ASXL1   2   43  4   ASXL1-4 105 1
ASXL1   1   86  4   ASXL1-4 105 1
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb3cQ.jpg  this is the linegraph for asxl1-3, where the dotted line is currently being plotted as x=10, but would like it to look at column zed and plot the line at x=110.

Comment: Is the column 'zed' single valued? I would try to put x=df['zed'].

Comment: You can check here [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) This similar like Seaborn and also works on Pandas. This has a option of Groupby that allows you to group the similar sections from the dataframe column and makes it easy to plot.

Comment: Can you make a runnable example with synthetic data?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed responce, i have been home sick for the past few days. @tcaswell- I just updated my post to have a runable example.

Comment: @gabra- when i put x=df['Zed'] i get the following error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). As you can see from the example data i posted above, the value for zed is different for every patient.